# in working with ejb I have problems understanding something from the code below. it works perfect just confused about the lookup process(see code)

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, jndi

in working with ejb I have problems understanding something from the code below. it works perfect just confused about the lookup process(see code)

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import com.coolstory.TheBeanRemote;


public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws NamingException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Properties p= new Properties();
        p.put((Context.PROVIDER_URL) ,"t3://localhost:7001");
    p.put((Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY),"weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
        try {
            //create a context  and pass in properties which contain lookup information
            Context ctx= new InitialContext(p);
            TheBeanRemote bean= (TheBeanRemote)ctx.lookup("mrBean#com.coolstory.TheBeanRemote"); /*what is the pound sign function here I am confused */
            String x= ctx.getEnvironment().toString();
            System.out.println(x);
            bean.sayhi();
            System.out.println("Main.main()"+ bean.sayhi());
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please elaborate. Which part of the lookup process confuses you?

Comment: Presumably `/*what is the pound sign function here I am confused */`.

Answer (score 0):

The convention is `<ejb-name>#<interface-name>`, so the `#` is just a delimiter between the EJB name and the interface name.